# Alfresco How to change default Url in alfresco

Tags: alfresco

Who can help me.

I want change ulr in afresco example like '<`https://localhost:8080/alfresco`>' to  '<`https://localhost:8080/ECM`>'.

I have tried in many way but still not efective.

Comment: What are you deploying the war into? That's likely to make a big difference as to how you deploy it with a different URL pattern

Comment: Install a reverse proxy like apache http mod_proxy to configure whatever you want. You can change the url, but then you'd need to change the war file name and ALL the references to it.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you're running a "standard" alfresco-tomcat system:

Rename your alfresco.war-file & restart your tomcat.
if you are using share then you'll also have to change the remote-configs in share-config-custom.xml

Or install, configure & use a reverse proxy like Apache & mod_proxy as Tahir mentioned

Comment: Also remember to change the alfresco context in the alfresco-global.properties file.